# How to upload a file to an FTP server in CMake?

Tags: cmake

After a target is built, I want to upload the result to an FTP server. How to do this?

I know the command **[`file(UPLOAD...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html)** but this would be executed at configuration only.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably add a custom command at post build e.g. like:

```
project(my_project)
...
add_custom_command(TARGET my_project
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ftp -u ftp://user:secret@ftp.example.com my-local-file.txt
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't believe this is portable. Is it? The whole point of using CMake is that it makes things portable. If I have to call system specific commands, then I believe I would rather wrap all this in a Python script instead.

Comment: No it's not portable, but you can also run a script instead of the ftp command, yes. Or you add different custom commands depending on the platform.

Comment: This is what I actually did. I used a python script doing the job. And I simply call it from CMake. But I thought that as the file(UPLOAD...) was existing, some similar command would also be available. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is close but what you do is make a cmake script with just the file(UPLOAD...) and the custom command invokes `$CMAKE -P upload.script`.  This makes it portable.